# Why mockStatic doesn't behave as expected?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

mockito-core version: 1.10.19

powermock version: 1.6.6

I try to mock some static methods, but the output confuses me.
Here is my code:

```
class ClassWithStatics {
    public static int getNextInt() {
        return getInt() + 1;
    }

    public static int getInt() {
        return 1;
    }

    public static long getTime() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassWithStatics.class, System.class})
public class StubJustOneStatic {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassWithStatics.class);
        Mockito.when(ClassWithStatics.getInt()).thenReturn(0);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        Mockito.when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(12345L);

        System.out.println("Next Int: " + ClassWithStatics.getNextInt());
        System.out.println("Int: " + ClassWithStatics.getInt());
        System.out.println("Time:" + ClassWithStatics.getTime());
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Next Int: 0
Int: 0
Time:0
```

But when i use the following code,  `ClassWithStatics.getTime()` prints exactly what i want.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassWithStatics.class, System.class})
public class StubJustOneStatic {
    @Test
    public void test() {
         //  PowerMockito.mockStatic(ClassWithStatics.class);
         //  Mockito.when(ClassWithStatics.getInt()).thenReturn(0);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
        Mockito.when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(12345L);

        //  System.out.println("Next Int: " + ClassWithStatics.getNextInt());
        //  System.out.println("Int: " + ClassWithStatics.getInt());
        System.out.println("Time:" + ClassWithStatics.getTime());
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: And the usual rant: using static methods make your code hard to test. Turning to PowerMock is the wrong answer. Write easy-to-test code instead ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking the static class and this means that if you do not explicitly define the when()..then() behavior, Mockito will return default values (0 in case of long).

You would have to use spying in order to mock only certain methods and let other methods run as implemented:

```
PowerMockito.spy(ClassWithStatics.class);
Mockito.when(ClassWithStatics.getInt()).thenReturn(5);
```

Now when you invoke:

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
Mockito.when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(12345L);

System.out.println("Time:" + ClassWithStatics.getTime());
```

You should get `5` when invoking `ClassWithStatics.getInt()` and `12345L` when invoking `ClassWithStatics.getTime()`.

Comment: it works.  I should use spying as I wanna invoke the real getNextInt() method. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great! Glad i could help